# Having trouble reading text file

Tags: c++, fstream, cin

**This is my text file named read.txt:**

```
ID Name
22 Joe
33 Jim
ID Name
44 Bob
55 Jeff
ID Name
66 Mike
```

**Task:**
Every time the code encounters the string "ID", it has to add the line after it into a list. So, for example:

```
(List1)
22 Joe
33 Jim

(List2)
44 Bob
55 Jeff

(List3)
66 Mike
```

**Problem:** I'm having trouble with reading the text file. I looked up other questions that have been asked on here and saw that `cin.fail()` might be of use. So, I looked it up in my textbook and tried implementing it but the program just displays a blank screen when I compile. When I take out all the strings `ID` and just have the numbers and names, the code works perfectly.

**This is the section of my code:**

```
int main()
{
    ifstream file_read;
    file_read.open("read.txt");

    LinkedList list1, list2, list3, list4;  //lists are of type linkedlist
    string name, name2, name3;      
    int ID;                 
    int counter = 0;    //counter initialized
    while (file_read.is_open()) {   //run loop until end of file reached
        if (file_read.fail()) {      //when cin fails
            counter++;               //increment counter
            if (counter == 1) {       //if counter is 1
                file_read >> ID >> name;    
                list1.Add(name, ID);   //add following names to list1
            }
            if (counter == 2) {  //if counter value is 2 
                file_read >> ID >> name2;
                list2.Add(name2, ID);  //add to list 2
            }
            if (counter == 3) {    //if counter value is 3
                file_read >> ID >> name3;
                list3.Add(name3, ID);   //add to list 3
            }
        }
    }
    file_read.close();
}
```

*List 1,2,3 are linkedlists. Add is a function of linked list. These parts of the code work correcly, I am only having trouble with the text-file portion*

**Output:** I'm getting a blank screen.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can split the text file data into sections whenever I encounter a string? Thank you in advance.

Comment: ([Don't use `while (!file_read.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong))

Comment: `if (counter = 1) {` => `if (counter == 1) {`

Comment: `continue` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Spend some time putting together a [MCVE] and you'll soon find out what the problems are. That's your job, not ours!!

Comment: Those `else continue;` lines are quite superfluous. `counter` will only have one value at a time (once the comparisons are fixed).

Comment: @Biffen is completely right here. Conditioning only on eof is not idiomatic and completely ignores cases where the read could fail for any other reason.  [Check out this awesome article on C++ IO streams](http://umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/basicCppio.pdf)

Comment: I removed the incorrect `else continue;` statements, fixed the `while` loop parameter. Is there still an error with this code? because I am still getting a blank output.

Comment: @ss1111 `=` vs `==` is a *huge* issue.

Comment: @Biffen I was following the first comment because I thought `==` was used to check if the condition is true that they are equal. But now I am confused about whether to use `=` or `==`.

Comment: @ss1111 You want `==` in this case. May I suggest a reread of your favourite C++ learning source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean

```
if (! file_read.fail()) {
```

instead of `if (file_read.fail())`? After all, you only want to add to the list if the read was successful.